# Plotting 3D Polygons

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

### I was unsuccessful browsing web for a solution for the following simple question:

How to draw 3D polygon (say a filled rectangle or triangle) using vertices values?
I have tried many ideas but all failed, see:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
x = [0,1,1,0]
y = [0,0,1,1]
z = [0,1,0,1]
verts = [zip(x, y,z)]
ax.add_collection3d(PolyCollection(verts),zs=z)
plt.show()
```

I appreciate in advance any idea/comment.

**Updates based on the accepted answer:**

```
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d as a3
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

ax = a3.Axes3D(pl.figure())
for i in range(10000):
    vtx = np.random.rand(3,3)
    tri = a3.art3d.Poly3DCollection([vtx])
    tri.set_color(colors.rgb2hex(np.random.rand(3)))
    tri.set_edgecolor('k')
    ax.add_collection3d(tri)
pl.show()
```

Here is the result:
[image]

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I think you've almost got it.   Is this what you want?

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig, auto_add_to_figure=False)
fig.add_axes(ax)
x = [0,1,1,0]
y = [0,0,1,1]
z = [0,1,0,1]
verts = [list(zip(x,y,z))]
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts))
plt.show()
```

[image]
You might also be interested in art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, both the answer and update code result in visualizations that are **incorrect**, but for different reasons.  Explanations are provided below.

##### A Solution

First consider a 'correct' answer.  Matplotlib will correctly plot filled polygons.  Polygons are *planar*.  The four example vertices in the question are not planar. But these vertices can be used to define two triangles.  The `verts` parameter in the [art3d.Poly3DCollection](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection.set_zsort) is a list of (N, 3) array-like sequence of polygons.  Using a list of the four vertices, v, and a list of vertex indices for two triangular faces, f, a simple solution is:

```
import pylab as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection

v = [ [0,0,0], [1,0,1], [1,1,0], [0,1,1] ]   # 4 vertices
f = [ [0,1,3], [1,2,3] ]                     # 2 faces
verts =  [ [ v[i] for i in p] for p in f]    # list comprehension
c = ['C0','C3']                              # 2 colors

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.set(xlim=(0,1), ylim=(0,1), zlim=(0,1))
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts,color=c))
plt.show()
```

which produces a figure of two polygons with different colors as:

[image: two surface solution]

This even works for a list of polygons with a mixed number of sides. For example, a collection of square and triangular faces:

[image: closed surface]

The code to produce this figure is:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection

z = 2**(1/2)
v =  [ [1,1, 1], [-1,1, 1], [-1,-1, 1], [1,-1, 1], 
       [z,0,-1], [ 0,z,-1], [-z, 0,-1], [0,-z,-1] ]      # 8 vertices
f4 = [ [0,1,2,3], [7,6,5,4] ]
fa = [ [0,3,4], [1,0,5], [2,1,6], [3,2,7] ]
fb = [ [4,5,0], [5,6,1], [6,7,2], [7,4,3] ]
f = f4 + fa + fb                                         # 10 faces
verts =  [ [ v[i] for i in p] for p in f]                # list comprehension
colors = ['teal']*2 + ['indianred']*4 + ['olivedrab']*4  # 10 colors

fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.set(xlim=(-1.5,1.5), ylim=(-1.5,1.5), zlim=(-1.5,1.5))
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts,color=colors))

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Notice that the colors in the `colors` list are in the same order as the list of faces in the `f` list.  Also, if all the polygons are of the same type, for example all triangles or all quadrilaterals, it is convenient to use Numpy arrays for the vertices, v, and faces, f.  Then the `verts` can be simply defined as:

```
verts = v[f]
```

instead of using Python list comprehension.  In addition, if shading is used, all polygons must be defined with the list of vertex indices for each face consistent with a right-handed or left-handed vertex order.

##### Problem 1. Non-planar faces

Defining the verts list by:

```
x = [0,1,1,0]
y = [0,0,1,1]
z = [0,1,0,1]
verts = [list(zip(x,y,z))]
```

results in defining one four-sided face.  The visualization 'appears' correct for the Matplotlib default axes view with azim=-60. However, the visual interpretation is inconsistent for different views.  This is shown below by comparing three views. This is not a Matplotlib problem but a problem of incorrectly defining a 4-sided polygon using four vertices which are not in the same plane.

[image: incorrect views]

Using the two triangular face solution, the visualization of this 3D collection is consistent for any viewing direction:

[image: correct views]

A warped surface can be constructed from the four vertices, but this requires subdividing the surface into multiple polygons.  Using the Matplotlib third-party package [S3Dlib](https://s3dlib.org/), the following ruled surface was constructed from 512 triangles.

[image: ruled surface]

In this case, the top and bottom of the surface was colored blue and red, respectively.  Then shading was applied to enhance the visualization of the surface.  No longer simple but correct.

Matplotlib 3D visualizations can handle a polycollection of multiple polygons by correctly stacking the polygons along the view direction.  However, Matplotlib cannot *directly* handle the visualization when polygons intersect. Visualizations will be incorrect and  dependent on the view.

For example, consider three triangles defined as:

```
v = [ [0,0,0], [1,0,0], [1,1,0], [0,1,0],
      [0,0,1], [1,0,1], [1,1,1], [0,1,1] ]    # 8 vertices
f = [ [1,6,4], [1,3,5], [0,2,7] ]             # 3 triangles
c = [ 'C0', 'C1', 'C2' ]
```

These are three intersecting triangles, but when viewed from different orientations, the visualizations are inconsistent.

[image: incorrect intersecting triangles]

By subdividing each of the three triangles into smaller triangles, the intersections among the three triangles can be consistently visualized independent of the view:

[image: correct intersecting triangles]

The above figure of intersecting triangles was created with Matplotlib using S3Dlib.

The question update produces a collection of random triangular polygons. However, as demonstrated in the above simple example, such a large number of polygons will be intersecting.  As a result, the actual collection will not be correctly displayed without accounting for the intersections.

By closely examining a similar collection of triangles from different orientations, the visualization anomalies can be detected. This is shown in the following figure.

[image: random triangles]

A possible solution could be to subdivide the numerous triangles into smaller polygons to account for the intersections.  However this method would result in a significant computational cost. The problem solution is no longer 'simple'.

##### Summary

Both problems could have been identified by viewing the 3D collection from various viewing directions. That way, during development, the solution method may have been identified as flawed.

As additional note: [seed](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.seed.html) the Numpy random generator prior to sampling, for example using :

```
np.random.seed(seed)
```

Doing this allows using the same set of random numbers during code development and verification.