# How to plot polytopes and Lemke-Howson path in Python?

Tags: python, plot, graphics, polyhedra

I have implemented a Lemke-Howson algorithm in python and I'd like to be able to show the game polytopes and the path that the algorithm follows graphically. I want something simple like this:

[image]

Comment: What format is the data in?

Comment: Please show any attempts you've made so far.

Comment: I don't really know where to start from. I've looked for libraries for plotting polytopes and graphics tutorials, but I'm still confused.

I just want to be able to draw a picture like these given that I have the coordinates. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a quick solution to plotting polytopes and paths that I know of. However you can plot multiple polygons on once plot and then plot your paths over them.  You will need to combine ideas and implementations from the following references:

- [SO question (Plotting 3D Polygons in python-matplotlib)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4622057/2087463)
- [`LinPy` tutorial](http://linpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html)
- [`matplotlib` path tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/path_tutorial.html)
- [`matplotlib` shape and collections examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/shapes_and_collections/artist_reference.html)
- [`polytope 0.1.1`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/polytope)
- [`mplot3d` 3D tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html)