# Plot3d in Python

Tags: python, matlab, mplot3d

I have an OBJ File Generated by Meshlab with Vertices and Faces data.
In MATLAB i used the function ''patch'' with Vertices data in 1 array (5937x3) and Faces (11870x3) data in another and the result is this:

```
Simplified version of the code

[V,F] = read_vertices_and_faces_from_obj_file(filename);

patch('Vertices',V,'Faces',F,'FaceColor','r','LineStyle','-')

axis equal
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oILg.jpg)

The question is,how can I do that in Python ? There's a simple way like in Matlab??

I'll really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet would be to make use of the [`mplot3d` toolkit](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/) from the `matplotlib` library.

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622057/plotting-3d-polygons-in-python-matplotlib). Perhaps this slightly edited code excerpt from that question will help you.

**The Code:**

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
# Specify 4 vertices
x = [0,1,1,0] # Specify x-coordinates of vertices
y = [0,0,1,1] # Specify y-coordinates of vertices
z = [0,1,0,1] # Specify z-coordinates of vertices
verts = [zip(x, y, z)] # [(0,0,0), (1,0,1), (1,1,0), (0,1,1)]
tri = Poly3DCollection(verts) # Create polygons by connecting all of the vertices you have specified
tri.set_color(colors.rgb2hex(sp.rand(3))) # Give the faces random colors
tri.set_edgecolor('k') # Color the edges of every polygon black
ax.add_collection3d(tri) # Connect polygon collection to the 3D axis
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks!! I'll try that.