# How to plot 3D Polygons

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d, matplotlib-3d

In my quest to somehow get 3D polygons to actually plot, I came across the following script (EDIT: modified slightly): [Plotting 3D Polygons in python-matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622057/plotting-3d-polygons-in-python-matplotlib)

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.collections import Poly3DCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
x = [0,1,1,0]
y = [0,0,1,1]
z = [0,1,0,1]
verts = [zip(x, y,z)]
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts),zs=z)
plt.show()
```

But when I run that, I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: object of type 'zip' has no len()
```

It seems that this may be a Python 2 vs. 3 thing, as I am running in Python 3, and that post is five years old. So I changed the third-to-last line to:

```
verts = list(zip(x, y, z))
```

Now verts shows up in the variable list, but I still get an error:

```
TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration
```

What? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had a similar problem with the zipping. I support the thesis it is a python 2.x vs 3.x thing.

However, I've found somewhere that apparently works:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
x = [0, 1, 1, 0]
y = [0, 0, 1, 1]
z = [0, 1, 0, 1]
verts = [list(zip(x, y, z))]
print(verts)
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts), zdir='z')
plt.show()
```

I've thus made two changes:

1. replaced the line:
   `from matplotlib.collections import Poly3DCollection`
   by:
   `from matplotlib.mplot3.art3d import Poly3DCollection`.

   I don't know where your import statement originates from, but it didn't seem to work for me
2. changed the line: `verts = list(zip(x,y,z))` to `verts = [list(zip(x, y, z))]`

Somehow, the latter seems to work. Having just started myself with python, I cannot offer an iron-clad explanation. However, here goes nothing: the class Poly3DCollection requires as the first input parameter a "collection", hence a list of lists. In this case, only list is given, which is assumed thus missed a level. By adding another level to it (via the [...]) it worked.

I've got no idea if this explanation makes sense, however it fits intuitively to me ;)

These modifications seem to work, as this code creates the desired 3D polygon (I've noticed that since this is my first post, I'm not allowed to post a proof-of-the-pudding figure.... )

hope this was useful,

kind regards

Comment: You're right, `zip()` is the problem. In Python 2, `zip()` used to directly return a plain old list, which **matplotlib** can digest. In Python 3, `zip()` was changed to return an iterator, for use in contexts where not all of the items are needed at once (which could occupy a lot of memory if there are many) or where one stops consuming items before reaching the end. That **matplotlib** function cannot digest an iterator, so `list()` flattens the iterator into a list and makes it work again.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use **Poly3DCollection** instead of PolyCollection:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
x = [0,1,1,0]
y = [0,0,1,1]
z = [0,1,0,1]
verts = [zip(x,y,z)]
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts), zs=z)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Oops--I failed to mention that I was already trying Poly3DCollection. Again, the zipping is what is causing the error. I do not know how to fix this.

Comment: Works for me when I remove the zs parameter. That is:
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts)) works. ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts), zs=z) returns error

Comment: You don't need `zs=z` if you use `Poly3DCollection` as the z-axis value is already include.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a current solution, in case you get the Error `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)`, due to how `verts` is constructed in the other solutions:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
x = [0,1,1,0]
y = [0,0,1,1]
z = [0,1,0,1]
verts = [[xx,yy,zz] for xx,yy,zz in zip(x,y,z)]     # NEW
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts))
plt.show()
```