# Python joining adjacent points with line in 3D scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d

I have got two sets of (x,y.z) coordinates which I plotted in a 3D scatter plot with Matplotlib. Now, I would like to connect each resulting quadrilateral with a plane surface.
I've seen how to draw a 2D polygon in a 3D space from [Plotting 3D Polygons in python-matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622057/plotting-3d-polygons-in-python-matplotlib).

What I don't know how to do is to group the points of my set into 4 points groups in order to draw polygons. I would be happy even if I managed to connect each point with its neighbours with a straight line.

My set of points lies very close to a planar distribution; but it is just a set of coordinates, there is no constraint underneath it.[image]

My code:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_figure(data):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

    ax.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], data[:, 2],
           c='r', s=20, linewidths=None)

    ax.axis('equal')
    ax.axis('tight')

    plt.show()


data = [[ 1900., 800., 442.82], [ 1900., 900., 463.04], [ 1900.,1000., 
473.06], [ 1900.,1100., 485.07], 
[ 1900.,1200., 498.63], [ 1900.,1300., 513.83], [ 1900.,1400., 536.1 ], [ 
1900.,1500., 551.29],
[ 1900.,1600., 566.5 ], [ 1900.,1700., 581.65], [ 1900.,1800., 603.91], [ 
2000., 800., 453.5 ], 
[ 2000., 900., 473.75], [ 2000.,1000., 487.14], [ 2000.,1100., 499.48], [ 
2000.,1200., 513.39],
[ 2000.,1300., 528.92], [ 2000.,1400., 551.85], [ 2000.,1500., 567.35], [ 
2000.,1600., 582.9 ], 
[ 2000.,1700., 598.4 ], [ 2000.,1800., 621.32], [ 2100., 800., 464.23], [ 
2100., 900., 485.34],
[ 2100.,1000., 502.87], [ 2100.,1100., 515.71], [ 2100.,1200., 530.13], [ 
2100.,1300., 546.14], 
[ 2100.,1400., 570.05], [ 2100.,1500., 586.1 ], [ 2100.,1600., 602.15], [ 
2100.,1700., 618.15], 
[ 2100.,1800., 642.09], [ 2200., 800., 474.94], [ 2200., 900., 498.72], [ 
2200.,1000., 516.91], 
[ 2200.,1100., 530.09], [ 2200.,1200., 544.83], [ 2200.,1300., 561.2 ], [ 
2200.,1400., 585.8 ], 
[ 2200.,1500., 602.17], [ 2200.,1600., 618.55], [ 2200.,1700., 634.89], [ 
2200.,1800., 659.46], 
[ 2300., 800., 487.69], [ 2300., 900., 513.43], [ 2300.,1000., 532.64], [ 
2300.,1100., 546.32], 
[ 2300.,1200., 561.57], [ 2300.,1300., 578.43], [ 2300.,1400., 604.03], [ 
2300.,1500., 620.89], 
[ 2300.,1600., 637.76], [ 2300.,1700., 654.62], [ 2300.,1800., 680.23], [ 
2400., 800., 500.75], 
[ 2400., 900., 526.83], [ 2400.,1000., 546.69], [ 2400.,1100., 560.71], [ 
2400.,1200., 576.3 ], 
[ 2400.,1300., 593.52], [ 2400.,1400., 619.78], [ 2400.,1500., 636.98], [ 
2400.,1600., 654.2 ], 
[ 2400.,1700., 671.38], [ 2400.,1800., 697.66], [ 2500., 800., 516.1 ], [ 
2500., 900., 542.71], 
[ 2500.,1000., 563.6 ], [ 2500.,1100., 578.12], [ 2500.,1200., 594.18], [ 
2500.,1300., 611.89],
[ 2500.,1400., 639.17], [ 2500.,1500., 656.87], [ 2500.,1600., 674.58], [ 
2500.,1700., 692.26],
[ 2500.,1800., 719.53], [ 2600., 800., 530.05], [ 2600., 900., 556.98], [ 
2600.,1000., 578.51],
[ 2600.,1100., 593.37], [ 2600.,1200., 609.77], [ 2600.,1300., 627.81], [ 
2600.,1400., 655.76],
[ 2600.,1500., 673.82], [ 2600.,1600., 691.86], [ 2600.,1700., 709.87], [ 
2600.,1800., 737.83]]
data = np.asarray(data)

plot_figure (data)
```

Comment: If you already have a quadrilateral grid, you might directly use `plot_surface`. If you have the points from such a grid, you may want to bring them into the correct shape first, such that `plot_surface` will understand them. If you need help with that, you probably would want to update your question and show the actual code you have. I would guess this is in any case easier than drawing individual polygons.

Comment: my coordinates set does not form a grid. They don't lie on a plane, even if from the picture they seem to be very close to a plane.

Comment: From the plot you show it looks like it. In any case, please provide your data and the code to show the plot if you want an answer.

Comment: ok, I added the code with the coordinates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of individual polygons you may use a `plot_surface` or `plot_wireframe` plot. To be able to use this, you need to reshape your data to constitute a grid. In this case, this is rather easy, as the data is already in a useful order.

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#data = data from the question
data = np.asarray(data)

a,b = len(np.unique(data[:,0])),  len(np.unique(data[:,1]))

X = data[:,0].reshape(a,b).T
Y = data[:,1].reshape(a,b).T
Z = data[:,2].reshape(a,b).T

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z)

ax.axis('equal')
ax.axis('tight')

plt.show()
```

[image]

or with

```
ax.plot_wireframe(X,Y,Z)
```

[image]

Comment: In the first case is it possible to mark the grid lines (each quadrilatral border)? I imagine I can just superimpose the wireframe..

Comment: You can set the edgecolor, `ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z, edgecolor="limegreen")`