# Plot a plane in 3D python plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to draw a plane in 3D python plot, without using `np.meshgrid`. I have done some Google search and found this code, [enter link description here](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/users/path_tutorial.html). The heart of this code is command `PathPatch` and it works very well in 2D plots. But, I want to plot the vertex given below in 3D plot:

```
verts = [(0., 0.,0.),
         (0., 1.,0.),
         (1., 1.,0.),
         (1., 0.,0.)]
```

Is there any command similar to `PathPatach` for 3D graphics or any other way to draw the plane in 3D plot? Please help.

Comment: You could draw a polygon

Comment: `ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection([verts]))` as in the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622057/plotting-3d-polygons-in-python-matplotlib).