# Create an image for a polygon where inside is white and outside is black

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I want to create an image that has a polygon drawn as white inside and outside from data that I already have. So afterwards I can find the inside and outside for each pixel in the image. I've been looking that to create such an image you need the set of vertices from the polygon. I do have them but they are 3D data, meaning that they are in xyz, and they aren't in32 and it seems that it needs to be int32. Like this:

````
```
[[-0.707      -0.707       0.        ]
 [-0.62271429 -0.74328571  0.211     ]
 [-0.59420137 -0.74831741  0.26970307]
 [-0.50498361 -0.74242623  0.41552459]
 [-0.4176378  -0.72176378  0.53222047]
 [-0.34445357 -0.69651357  0.616105  ]
 [-0.211      -0.631       0.735     ]
 [-0.631      -0.211      -0.735     ]
 [-0.69651357 -0.34445357 -0.616105  ]
 [-0.72176378 -0.4176378  -0.53222047]
 [-0.74242623 -0.50498361 -0.41552459]
 [-0.74831741 -0.59420137 -0.26970307]
 [-0.74328571 -0.62271429 -0.211     ]]
```
````

Is there a way that I can transform this points so I can draw the same contour in 3D as a 2D image?. That means finding the 2D pixel coordinates of a 3D Point

I actually don't know how to start or is it possible.

I tried to translate and rotate the contour, and I'm thinking about scaling the contour to be int32 however I'm clueless if this is going to help my overall problem in the long run.

Comment: Interesting question, are you certain that the points are on the same plane?

Comment: Do you want [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622057/plotting-3d-polygons-in-python-matplotlib)?

Comment: I erased some points, to just illustrate how the data looks like. But no what I want is an image to later use.

Comment: What I mean is to find the 2D pixel coordinates of a 3D Point.