# How can I plot a filled rectangular prism with matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I have been trying to use the method described in this post with Poly3DCollection to plot rotated rectangular prisms with just their vertices.
[Plotting 3D Polygons in python-matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622057/plotting-3d-polygons-in-python-matplotlib)

However, I'm not getting a rectangular/quadrilateral surfaces as I would expect and I get a surface that is weirdly segmented with triangles instead.

[image: Rectangular Prism Plot]

If anyone has any help, that'd be appreciated!

```
    for i in range(sample_size):
        # Generate randomly sized rectangle
        sample_shape = Rectangle(17, 7, 5)

        # Rotate rectangle randomly on the z-axis
        angle_of_rotation = random.randint(0, 359)
        sample_shape.rotate_rectangle(angle_of_rotation)

        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = Axes3D(fig)
        x, y, z = sample_shape.matrix[:, 0], sample_shape.matrix[:, 1], sample_shape.matrix[:, 2]
        verts = [list(zip(x, y, z))]
        ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts), zs=z)
        ax.set_xlim3d(-30, 30)
        ax.set_ylim3d(-30, 30)
        ax.set_zlim3d(-5, 10)

        plt.show()
```

My rectangle class looks like this

```py
class Rectangle:

    def __init__(self, x: float, y: float, z: float):
        corner_a = np.array((-x, -y, z))
        corner_b = np.array((-x, y, z))
        corner_c = np.array((x, y, z))
        corner_d = np.array((x, -y, z))
        corner_e = np.array((-x, -y, 0))
        corner_f = np.array((-x, y, 0))
        corner_g = np.array((x, y, 0))
        corner_h = np.array((x, -y, 0))
        self.matrix = np.array((corner_a, corner_b, corner_c, corner_d,
                                corner_e, corner_f, corner_g, corner_h))
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with your code?