# How to build a 3D regular polygon in python, knowing the vertices

Tags: python, 3d, polygon, vertices

I have some data that describes the vertices of a regular 3D polygon (X,Y,Z). I am trying to build a cuboid from that with matplotlib, mayavi and others, but i did not succeed so far, yet I feel this is probably a dumb question with an obvious solution.

The data is really simples as:
p1,p2,p3,p4 are the anticlockwise coordinates of the vertices in the base (X,Y,Z).
p5,p6,p7,p8 are the anticlockwise coordinates of the vertices in the top (X,Y,Z).

Help please.

```
P1=[88.10785899 38.69449727  2.07606017]
P2=[96.11246382 38.69449727  2.07606017]
P3=[96.11246382 24.68643882  2.07606017]
P4=[88.10785899 24.68643882  2.07606017]
P5=[88.10785899 38.69449727 10.080665]
P6=[96.11246382 38.69449727 10.080665]
P7=[96.11246382 24.68643882 10.080665]
P8=[88.10785899 24.68643882 10.080665]
```

Comment: just plot a line from P1 to P2, from P2 to P3...  It would be much easier if instead of 8 variables you have a list. Or you want a solid object?

Comment: Yep, I originally did that. But in fact I need the solid object, since I will perform some mathematical operations in that later.

Comment: check that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622057/plotting-3d-polygons-in-python-matplotlib

Comment: Oh, I've tried. Still did not work as well :(